# DiscordJS Listing all server channels in select menu

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to list out all the channels from the server and put them all into a Select Menu but I get the following error:

```
data.components[0].components[0].options: Must be between 1 and 25 in length.
```

Code:

```js
    run: async (interaction) => {
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#4ccdea')
            .setTitle('Select a channel below.')
            .setTimestamp()

        let selectmenu = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageSelectMenu()
                    .setCustomId('channel')
                    .setPlaceholder('Nothing selected')
                    .addOptions([{
                        label: `Cancel`,
                        description: 'Cancel the channel selection',
                        value: 'cancel',
                    }])
            )

        interaction.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => {
            selectmenu.components[0].addOptions([{
                label: `${channel.name}`,
                description: `${channel.name}`,
                value: `${channel.id}`,
            }]);
        })
        await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], components: [selectmenu] });
    }
```

Comment: This would happen if there were more than 25 channels in the server. Maybe you can filter them into text channels and voice channels to reduce the number?

Comment: And that means you can't add more than 25 channels.

Comment: True. If there are more than 25 text channels or voice channels, you would still get the error

Comment: You can filter them by using `const textChannels = interaction.guild.channels.cache.filter(ch => ch.type === 'GUILD_TEXT')`

Comment: this does solve the filtering issue, but how would i counteract the error if the server has over 25 channels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that you can't have more than 25 options in a select menu. As you have already an option (`cancel`), you can only add 24 channels at a time.

A quick and dirty solution is to just send the [first 24](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=first) channels, like this:

```js
let selectmenu = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
  new MessageSelectMenu()
    .setCustomId('channel')
    .setPlaceholder('Nothing selected')
    .addOptions([
      {
        label: `Cancel`,
        description: 'Cancel the channel selection',
        value: 'cancel',
      },
    ]),
);

interaction.guild.channels.cache.first(24).forEach((channel) => {
  selectmenu.components[0].addOptions([
    {
      label: `${channel.name}`,
      description: `${channel.name}`,
      value: `${channel.id}`,
    },
  ]);
});
await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], components: [selectmenu] });
```

You could also send more than one select menu. You will need to create an options array using [`map()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=map), create an action row for every 24 channels, and add the menu with the 24 options.

You can also create a helper function to chunkify your array:

```js
// helper function to slice arrays
function chunkify(arr, len) {
  let chunks = [];
  let i = 0;
  let n = arr.length;

  while (i < n)
    chunks.push(arr.slice(i, (i += len)));

  return chunks;
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```js
async (interaction) => {
  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#4ccdea')
    .setTitle('Select a channel below.')
    .setTimestamp();

  let selectMenus = [
    new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
      new MessageSelectMenu()
        .setCustomId('channel')
        .setPlaceholder('Nothing selected')
        .addOptions([
          {
            label: `Cancel`,
            description: 'Cancel the channel selection',
            value: 'cancel',
          },
        ]),
    ),
  ];
  await interaction.guild.channels.fetch();

  // iterate over the channels and create menu option objects
  let options = interaction.guild.channels.cache.map((channel) => ({
    label: channel.name,
    description: channel.name,
    value: channel.id,
  }));

  // if there is less than 24 fields, you can safely send the menu
  // in a single message
  if (options.length <= 24) {
    selectMenus[0].components[0].addOptions(options);
    await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], components: selectMenus });
  }

  // if there are more, you need to create chunks w/ max 24 fields
  // you can use the helper function created above
  const chunks = chunkify(options, 24);

  chunks.forEach((options, i) => {
    // if this is the first row, append the options
    if (i === 0)
      selectMenus[0].components[0].addOptions(options);

    // else just create a new action row with a new menu for each 24 fields
    else
      selectMenus.push(
        new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
          new MessageSelectMenu()
            .setCustomId(`channel-${i}`)
            .setPlaceholder('Nothing selected')
            .addOptions(options),
        ),
      );
  });

  await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], components: selectmenus });
}
```

One drawback of this is that the `customId` is not `channel`, but `channel`, `channel-1`, `channel-2`, etc. It means, you will need to make sure that when you handle the interaction, you check if the `interaction.customId.startsWith('channel')`.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.slice(0,25)` to only keep 25 first channels and put them in the select.

Comment: i tried `const textChannels = interaction.guild.channels.cache.filter(ch => ch.type === 'GUILD_TEXT').slice(0, 25)` but that does not work