# Expected: expected <= 25 - Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

this error only appears on **certain servers** but I don't know why
:

```
Expected: expected <= 25

Received:
35

at Object.run (x/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:757:72)
at x/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:201:66
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at NumberValidator.parse (x/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:201:29)
at SelectMenuBuilder.addOptions (x/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:651:28)
at SelectMenuBuilder.addOptions (x/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/StringSelectMenuBuilder.js:48:18)
at Object.run (x/Src/Interactions/Modals/Config.js:29:14)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Code :

```
const listedRoles = [];
        interaction.guild.roles.cache.forEach(role => { 
            
                listedRoles.push({
                    label: role.name,
                    description: "Use this role.",
                    emoji: "➕",
                    value: role.id
                
            })
        }); 
        
        const row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
            new SelectMenuBuilder()
            .setCustomId("RoleMenu")
            .setPlaceholder("Select a role.") //line 29.
            .addOptions(listedRoles)    
        )
```

Using **discord.js** v14.2.0 and **node.js** v19.7.0

Any idea ?
Thanks.

Comment: You can't have more than 25 options added to a select menu. That's a limitation of the discord API. This answer should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72829291/discordjs-listing-all-server-channels-in-select-menu/72831391#72831391

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you can only have a **maximum of 25 options in a single select menu**.

Since you're only displaying roles in a given server, I recommend:

- Updating to the latest discord.js version (as all previous ones have been deprecated).
- Use the `RoleSelectMenuBuilder`. This one displays all roles from a server dynamically, without having to specify options. Keep in mind that said builder is *not* available in `discord.js@14.2.0`.

That way, you could just do the following, and it would work without an issue:

```js
const row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
    new RoleSelectMenuBuilder()
        .setCustomId("RoleMenu")
        .setPlaceholder("Select a role.")
);
```

You can also [read more about select menus here](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/select-menus.html#building-and-sending-select-menus) and [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components#select-menus). Hope this helped :)